XSLT 1.0 to display combination of package numbers by SKU
I have a XSLT code where it displays the info in the form of table shown in the image where it display the packages information based on cartons numbers/package numbers individually
AS SHOWN IN IMAGE
enter image description here
this is the xslt code 1.0
<xsl:for-each select="packinglist_d"> <xsl:variable name="preCarton" select="./preceding-sibling::*[1]/@barcode_start" /> <xsl:variable name="curCarton" select="@barcode_start" /> <xsl:variable name="preItemNo" select="./preceding-sibling::*[1]/@item_no" /> <xsl:variable name="curItemNo" select="@item_no" /> <xsl:variable name="pl_no_inners" select="@no_inners" /> <xsl:variable name="pl_startCode" select="@barcode_start" /> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$pl_startCode != '' and $pl_startCode != '0'"> <fo:table-row> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:variable name="startCode" select="@barcode_start" /> <xsl:variable name="endCode" select="@barcode_end" /> <xsl:variable name="cartonNO1" select="concat($startCode , ' - ')" /> <xsl:variable name="cartonNO" select="concat($cartonNO1 , $endCode)" /> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$curCarton != $preCarton or position()=1"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="$cartonNO" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$curCarton != $preCarton or position()=1"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@order_no" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$curCarton != $preCarton or $curItemNo != $preItemNo or position()=1"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@item_no" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@memo2" /> </fo:block> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@memo1" /> </fo:block> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="@ship_pack !='PPK' and size_desc/@description !=''"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="size_desc/@description" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:when test="@ship_pack !='PPK'"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@size_code" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@ship_pack" /> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@ship_pack" /> </fo:block> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@qty_per_inner" /> </fo:block> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:variable name="noinners" select="@no_inners" /> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="contains($noinners, '.')"> <xsl:variable name="no_inners" select="substring-before($noinners,'.')" /> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="$no_inners" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@no_inners" /> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:variable name="nopack" select="@no_packages" /> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="contains($nopack, '.')"> <xsl:variable name="no_packages" select="substring-before($nopack,'.')" /> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="$no_packages" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@no_packages" /> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:variable name="qty1" select="@qty" /> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="contains($qty1, '.')"> <xsl:variable name="qty" select="substring-before($qty1,'.')" /> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="$qty" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@qty" /> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:variable name="numbr4" select="@numbr4" /> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="contains($numbr4, '.')"> <xsl:variable name="numbr41" select="translate($numbr4,',','')" /> <xsl:variable name="numbr42" select="format-number($numbr41,'#,##0.###')" /> <xsl:variable name="numbrafter" select="substring-after($numbr42,'.')" /> <xsl:variable name="strlen" select="string-length($numbrafter)" /> <xsl:call-template name="printdecimalpoint"> <xsl:with-param name="strlen" select="$strlen" /> <xsl:with-param name="invtotal1" select="$numbr42" /> </xsl:call-template> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$numbr4 != ''"> <xsl:variable name="numbr43" select="concat($numbr4,'.000')" /> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="$numbr43" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:variable name="totGrsWgt" select="@grs_wgt_pack" /> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="contains($totGrsWgt, '.')"> <xsl:variable name="totGrsWgt1" select="translate($totGrsWgt,',','')" /> <xsl:variable name="totGrsWgt2" select="format-number($totGrsWgt1,'#,##0.###')" /> <xsl:variable name="totafter" select="substring-after($totGrsWgt2,'.')" /> <xsl:variable name="strlen" select="string-length($totafter)" /> <xsl:call-template name="printdecimalpoint"> <xsl:with-param name="strlen" select="$strlen" /> <xsl:with-param name="invtotal1" select="$totGrsWgt2" /> </xsl:call-template> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$totGrsWgt != ''"> <xsl:variable name="totGrsWgt3" select="concat($totGrsWgt,'.000')" /> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="$totGrsWgt3" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="8.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@um_grs_wgt_pack" /> </fo:block> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:variable name="packMeas" select="@pack_meas" /> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="contains($packMeas, '.')"> <xsl:variable name="packMeas1" select="translate($packMeas,',','')" /> <xsl:variable name="packMeas2" select="format-number($packMeas1,'#,##0.###')" /> <xsl:variable name="totafter" select="substring-after($packMeas2,'.')" /> <xsl:variable name="strlen" select="string-length($totafter)" /> <xsl:call-template name="printdecimalpoint"> <xsl:with-param name="strlen" select="$strlen" /> <xsl:with-param name="invtotal1" select="$packMeas2" /> </xsl:call-template> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$packMeas != ''"> <xsl:variable name="packMeas3" select="concat($packMeas,'.000')" /> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="$packMeas3" /></fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="7.5pt" text-align="center"> </fo:block> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="8.5pt" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@um_pack_meas" /> </fo:block> </fo:table-cell> </fo:table-row> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </xsl:for-each>

and this is the sql query
<query name="packinglist_d" value="SELECT PACKING_LIST_D.ORDER_NO ORDER_NO,PACKING_LIST_D.ITEM_NO ITEM_NO,PACKING_LIST_D.ROW_NO ROW_NO,PACKING_LIST_D.SHIP_PACK SHIP_PACK,PACKING_LIST_D.MEMO1 MEMO1, PACKING_LIST_D.NUMBR3 NUMBR3,PACKING_LIST_D.SIZE_CODE SIZE_CODE,PACKING_LIST_D.MEMO2 as sku,PACKING_LIST_D.NO_INNERS NO_INNERS,PACKING_LIST_D.QTY_PER_PACK QTY_PER_PACK,PACKING_LIST_D.NO_PACKAGES NO_PACKAGES,PACKING_LIST_D.GRS_WGT_PACK GRS_WGT_PACK,PACKING_LIST_D.UM_GRS_WGT_PACK UM_GRS_WGT_PACK,PACKING_LIST_D.PACK_MEAS PACK_MEAS,PACKING_LIST_D.UM_PACK_MEAS UM_PACK_MEAS,PACKING_LIST_D.QTY_PER_INNER QTY_PER_INNER,PACKING_LIST_D.QTY QTY, PACKING_LIST_D.BARCODE_START BARCODE_START, PACKING_LIST_D.BARCODE_END BARCODE_END, PACKING_LIST_D.NUMBR4 NUMBR4 FROM PACKING_LIST_D PACKING_LIST_D WHERE PACKING_LIST_D.OWNER= ? AND PACKING_LIST_D.PACKING_LIST_NO=? ORDER BY CAST(PACKING_LIST_D.BARCODE_START AS INTEGER)" > <input> <column name="OWNER"/> <column name="PACKING_LIST_NO"/> </input> </query> 

now what I need to display is the same table but it should be displayed based combination of SKU
enter image description here
where package no is the combination of all cartons created for sku
when I try the below snippet
<fo:table-body> <xsl:for-each select="packinglist_d"> <xsl:variable name="pl_startCode" select="@barcode_start" /> <xsl:variable name="curSKU" select="@memo2" /> <xsl:variable name="preSKU" select="./preceding-sibling::*[1]/@memo2" /><xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$pl_startCode ! = '' and $pl_startCode != '0'"> <fo:table-row> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="$curSKU != $preSKU or position() = 1"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="8.5pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="concat(@barcode_start,'-',@barcode_end)" /> </fo:block> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </fo:table-cell> <fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="8.5pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@order_no" /> </fo:block> </fo:table-cell> fo:table-cell padding=".5mm" border-style="solid" border-width=".25mm"> <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="en" font-size="8.5pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="center"> <xsl:value-of select="@memo2" /> </fo:block></fo:table-cell> </fo:table-row> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </xsl:for-each> </fo:table-body>

it is working only for one table cell , later it display as same in first image when I try for multiple table cells i tried modifying the sql also but no use.
this is the sql I tried:
SELECT PACKING_LIST_D.OWNER,PACKING_LIST_D.ORDER_NO,PACKING_LIST_D.ITEM_NO,PACKING_LIST_D.MEMO2 as sku,PACKING_LIST_D.MEMO1,PACKIN`your text`G_LIST_D.SIZE_CODE,PACKING_LIST_D.SHIP_PACK,PACKING_LIST_D.QTY_PER_INNER,PACKING_LIST_D.NO_INNERS,CONCAT(MIN(BARCODE_START), '-',MAX(BARCODE_END)) as BARCODE_RANGE FROM PACKING_LIST_D PACKING_LIST_D WHERE PACKING_LIST_D.OWNER= ? AND PACKING_LIST_D.PACKING_LIST_NO=? GROUP BY PACKING_LIST_D.OWNER,PACKING_LIST_D.ORDER_NO,PACKING_LIST_D.ITEM_NO,PACKING_LIST_D.MEMO2,PACKING_LIST_D.MEMO1,PACKING_LIST_D.SIZE_CODE,PACKING_LIST_D.SHIP_PACK,PACKING_LIST_D.QTY_PER_INNER,PACKING_LIST_D.NO_INNERS order by MIN(BARCODE_START)::INTEGER


I find your question incomprehensible. Please provide a [mcve] showing an example of the XML input, your current stylesheet and the expected output - all as code within your question, not images in external links.

The input to XSLT transformation is an XML document. If your question is about XSLT then an SQL query is irrelevant.
